# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle...'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

Okay so I know this is an error that shows up A LOT on here, because I have read pretty much every one that has been posted, but it seems like a pretty generic error that can be caused by any number of things. Essentially my app crashes on first load with:

```
2014-06-20 00:36:01.044 Shopping List[1877:60b]
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:
'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/5C6E7163-019E-463A-8CDC-CFD01F563D67/
Shopping List.app> (loaded)' with name 'FpJ-Xv-ra6-view-VfE-Sv-DFW'
```

Now to clarify, I know the class that's causing the issue, and I think I know the root cause of the error, but I'm interested to know the actual reason for the crash, rather than just rewriting the class and moving on. Some background:

- I'm using a Storyboard file so that rules out any issues with NIB files.
- I have a class named "ShoppingListViewController" which by accident I set when creating to inherit from "UIViewController" rather than "UITableViewController"
- I changed the header file to attempt to correct the inheritance issue, so I simply changed....

This line:

```
@interface ShoppingListViewController : UIViewController
```

To:

```
@interface ShoppingListViewController : UITableViewController
```

- Whenever I attempt to include an instance of ShoppingListViewController in my Storyboard file, and have a segue to it, the app will crash immediately. With no instances of this controller, it runs fine.

So after some Googling into how Storyboarding works etc. what I'm guessing is happening is that Xcode has tried to generate a NIB file from my storyboard (FpJ-Xv-ra6-view-VfE-Sv-DFW), but after changing the class of this file, the NIB file is no longer compatible with my code, as it is supposed to be a View Controller? This is my very very dumbed down and poorly informed guess. But I'm just wondering in that case what would be the best way of changing which superclass a class inherits from in an iOS project without breaking stuff like this? And would there be a way that I can fix it without having to rewrite the class - the "correct" way I suppose?

Comment: Check that the root view in the appropriate storyboard scene is a UITableView - i.e. it is not contained in a UIView.  Also try removing the custom class from the scene in storyboard, build->clean and then reset the custom class to your `ShoppingListViewController`

Comment: While changing the class programatically in this way is fine, only a UITableViewController will be able to adopt the class in the interface builder. Are you sure you're subclassing the right controller?

Comment: @Paulw11 Tried cleaning before but not sure if the controller was still in the storyboard, so removed it and re-cleaned, but still the same issue.

Comment: @Literphor I'm sure, I drag in a Table View Controller to the storyboard from the object library (i.e. the second object in the list) and change its custom class in the identity inspector to ShoppingListViewController, add a root view controller segue from a tab bar controller downstream and this causes the app crash.

Comment: @LeonAves You know I just got done dealing with a similar error. It turned out I was trying to use a view before it completely initialized. This caused the app to look for a view that wasn't there, and it, in turn, tried to load a view from a nib file that didn't exist to compensate. I would check to make sure your views are available before using them. Maybe try moving all your logic to `-viewDidLoad` just to be safe that isn't the problem.